# Smooth scrolling polypill not working in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, smooth-scrolling, polyfills

I'm using https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll package to enable smooth scrolling in Safari.

I followed the doc and NextJS doc and created a custom app, in which I imported the polyfill import:

In `_app.js`:
`import smoothscroll from 'smoothscroll-polyfill'; // at the top level`

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  console.log('polyfilled');
  smoothscroll.polyfill();
  window.__forceSmoothScrollPolyfill__ = true;
}
```

I could see the print statement logged but smooth scrolling still doesn't work.

Here's the scrolling snippet that DOES work in Chrome:

```
element.scrollTo({
  left: 200,
  behavior: "smooth"
});
```

What am I doing wrong here? What can I do to get smooth scrolling to work in Safari in a NextJS app?!

Comment: Please note https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll/issues/157#issuecomment-879547490

Comment: @MinseoLee thank you so much! it's a hack but it worked!

Answer (score 0):

In the `if (typeof window !== "undefined")` statement, it looks like you're adding quote marks around `undefined`, so you're checking whether `window` equals the string `"undefined"`, which is always true.

Where are you placing the polyfill statement?

Putting it inside of a `useEffect` in _`app.js` worked like a charm for me. :-)

```js
// _app.js
import { polyfill } from 'smoothscroll-polyfill';

function App(...

   useEffect(() => {
        polyfill();
   },[])
```

Also, note that [they recommend against](https://www.npmjs.com/package/smoothscroll-polyfill#force-polyfill-implementation) forcing the polyfill with the `window.__forceSmoothScrollPolyfill__ = true;` statement, so removing that if not necessary is probably ideal.